# How to solve the procedure in last semicolon?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with line before end, something is happening with the closing semicolon, the message that I receive is below:

> CREATE PROCEDURE emp_info(IN p_first_name varchar(255), IN p_last_name varchar(255), OUT p_emp_no integer) BEGIN  SELECT   e.emp_no  INTO p_emp_no FROM   employees e  WHERE   e.first_name = p_first_name    AND e.last_name = p_last_name   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

```
use employees;
drop procedure if exists emp_info;

CREATE PROCEDURE emp_info(IN p_first_name varchar(255), IN p_last_name varchar(255), OUT p_emp_no integer)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        e.emp_no
    INTO p_emp_no FROM
        employees e
    WHERE
        e.first_name = p_first_name
            AND e.last_name = p_last_name;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to start with DELIMITER $$  and leaving a space between END $$ helps

```
drop procedure if exists emp_info;

DELIMIER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE emp_info(IN p_first_name varchar(255), IN p_last_name varchar(255), OUT p_emp_no integer)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        e.emp_no
    INTO p_emp_no FROM
        employees e
    WHERE
        e.first_name = p_first_name
            AND e.last_name = p_last_name;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```